# Vaadin designer does not generate the right files

Tags: vaadin, designer, vaadin10

I am using vaadin to develop UI for my client. When we have started the project we was using vaadin 13 thereafter we upgraded to vaadin 14.4.2.
Actually, we would like to use Vaadin designer to build UI, but it is generating html file instead of js, as you know vaadin 14 ignore @HtmlImport.
FYI I have tested it in demo project, it works fine, it generates the js file.
I guess that I have to change some configuration in my project to tell to Vaadin designer that we are using vaadin 14.
How i can fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to remove this dependency from pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>flow-server-compatibility-mode</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now, Vaadin designer is generating js files.